# API PLATFORM "Unable to generate an IRI for an entity"

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6

I have created an API using symfony 6 and I am doing the filters using api platform. I have 12 entities working perfectly but one is throwing me an error.

This is the error when doing a GET request:

```
Unable to generate an IRI for \"App\\Entity\\Titols\"."
```

This is Titols entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;

/**
 * Titols
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="obres")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
#[ApiResource]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['titol' => 'partial'])]
class Titols implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codi", type="string", length=18, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $codi;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titol", type="string", length=75, nullable=false)
     */
    private $titol;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="autor_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $autorId = '0';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tipus", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     */
    private $tipus;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="string", length=5, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $data = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="instrument", type="string", length=75, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $instrument = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dacomp", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $dacomp = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enreg", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $enreg = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="partitu", type="string", length=17, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $partitu = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="partice", type="string", length=17, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $partice = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pdf1", type="string", length=50, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $pdf1 = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pdf2", type="string", length=50, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $pdf2 = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pdf3", type="string", length=50, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $pdf3 = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="notes1", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $notes1 = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="notes2", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $notes2 = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mp3", type="string", length=50, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $mp3 = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uri_spotify", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $uriSpotify = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="notes3", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $notes3 = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="notes4", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $notes4 = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="arranjador_id", type="integer", nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $arranjadorId = NULL;


    public function getId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codi;
    }

    public function setId(string $codi): self
    {
        $this->codi = $codi;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodi(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codi;
    }

    public function setCodi(string $codi): self
    {
        $this->codi = $codi;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTitol(): ?string
    {
        return $this->titol;
    }

    public function setTitol(string $titol): self
    {
        $this->titol = $titol;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAutorId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->autorId;
    }

    public function setAutorId(int $autorId): self
    {
        $this->autorId = $autorId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTipus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tipus;
    }

    public function setTipus(string $tipus): self
    {
        $this->tipus = $tipus;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getData(): ?string
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function setData(?string $data): self
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInstrument(): ?string
    {
        return $this->instrument;
    }

    public function setInstrument(?string $instrument): self
    {
        $this->instrument = $instrument;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDacomp(): ?string
    {
        return $this->dacomp;
    }

    public function setDacomp(?string $dacomp): self
    {
        $this->dacomp = $dacomp;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEnreg(): ?string
    {
        return $this->enreg;
    }

    public function setEnreg(?string $enreg): self
    {
        $this->enreg = $enreg;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPartitu(): ?string
    {
        return $this->partitu;
    }

    public function setPartitu(?string $partitu): self
    {
        $this->partitu = $partitu;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPartice(): ?string
    {
        return $this->partice;
    }

    public function setPartice(?string $partice): self
    {
        $this->partice = $partice;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPdf1(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pdf1;
    }

    public function setPdf1(?string $pdf1): self
    {
        $this->pdf1 = $pdf1;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPdf2(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pdf2;
    }

    public function setPdf2(?string $pdf2): self
    {
        $this->pdf2 = $pdf2;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPdf3(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pdf3;
    }

    public function setPdf3(?string $pdf3): self
    {
        $this->pdf3 = $pdf3;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNotes1(): ?string
    {
        return $this->notes1;
    }

    public function setNotes1(?string $notes1): self
    {
        $this->notes1 = $notes1;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNotes2(): ?string
    {
        return $this->notes2;
    }

    public function setNotes2(?string $notes2): self
    {
        $this->notes2 = $notes2;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMp3(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mp3;
    }

    public function setMp3(?string $mp3): self
    {
        $this->mp3 = $mp3;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUriSpotify(): ?string
    {
        return $this->uriSpotify;
    }

    public function setUriSpotify(?string $uriSpotify): self
    {
        $this->uriSpotify = $uriSpotify;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNotes3(): ?string
    {
        return $this->notes3;
    }

    public function setNotes3(?string $notes3): self
    {
        $this->notes3 = $notes3;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNotes4(): ?string
    {
        return $this->notes4;
    }

    public function setNotes4(?string $notes4): self
    {
        $this->notes4 = $notes4;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getArranjadorId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->arranjadorId;
    }

    public function setArranjadorId(?int $arranjadorId): self
    {
        $this->arranjadorId = $arranjadorId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            "codi" => $this->getCodi(),
            "titol" => $this->getTitol(),
            "autor_id" => $this->getAutorId(),
            "tipus" => $this->getTipus(),
            "data" => $this->getData(),
            "instrument" => $this->getInstrument(),
            "dacomp" => $this->getDacomp(),
            "enreg" => $this->getEnreg(),
            "partitu" => $this->getPartitu(),
            "partice" => $this->getPartice(),
            "pdf1" => $this->getPdf1(),
            "pdf2" => $this->getPdf2(),
            "pdf3" => $this->getPdf3(),
            "notes1" => $this->getNotes1(),
            "notes2" => $this->getNotes2(),
            "mp3" => $this->getMp3(),
            "uri_spotify" => $this->getUriSpotify(),
            "notes3" => $this->getNotes3(),
            "notes4" => $this->getNotes4(),
            "arranjador_id" => $this->getArranjadorId()
        ];
    }
}
```

This is the only entity that I have where the id is not a number but a string, could be this the problem?

This is `getAll` function in `TitolsController.php` to optain the data:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/api/titols", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function getAll(TitolsRepository $titolsRepository): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(TitolsVoter::VIEW);

        $titols = $titolsRepository->findBy([], ['codi' => 'ASC'], 10);

        return $this->json($titols);
    }
```

Comment: Hello, what is your GET request?

Comment: Hey @GaryHoubre, I have updated the question. But the thing is that the GET request works perfectly when I comment all `use ApiPlatfrom ...` and also `#[ApiResource]
#[ApiFilter]`. I guess is something about the id that api platform does not like

Comment: Why do you have a custom controller? When you make exactly what request are you getting an error?

Comment: I review your problem, i have got a question, why custom controller ? If you remove your getAll function, can you retry the same GET Request ?

Comment: @yivi I have the custom controller to create the api requests (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT), then I found api platform so I'm using it to create filtering. I am getting the error when I do a GET request. The thing is that if i comment `#[ApiResource] and
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['titol' => 'partial'])]` I don't get any error, so I know it must be something about the id and api platform

Comment: @GaryHoubre The answer of the custom controller is the same as the one I answered to yivi and no, if I remove the `getAll` function it won't work

Comment: By using a custom controller you are breaking things, particularly the way you are using it. Api-Platform already comes built-in with search filters and order filters. Remove it and fix the issue without going through your custom controller.

Comment: I will try it. But all the other entities with custom controllers and then using api platform to create filters are working perfectly. This is not working because it is the entity without and id called id instead is called codi. That's what I was asking if I can use the codi as an id without api platform complaining

Comment: Yes, you can. But your question is derailed by not going through api-platform, but by actually through some custom controller which is not even declared in the resource annotation. Just get rid of it, try the endpoints and everything should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did not use the custom controller that I had and I added the `GET request` as api platform says in the documentation:

```
#[ApiResource(
    attributes: ["security" => "is_granted('PERMISSION_TITOL')"],
    collectionOperations: [
        'get' => ['method' => 'get'],
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'path' => '/api/titols'            
        ],
    ],
)]
```

This solved the error `Unable to generate an IRI for \"App\\Entity\\Titols\"."`